# mysql2 gem RoR in macos Monterey - first time installing RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, macos-monterey

Following the instructions [here](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/12-monterey#postgresql), i try running `rake db:create` and get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (~> 0.5)' in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally.
The source does not contain any versions of 'mysql2'
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then, when running `bundle install` i get this:

```
Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Also tried installing mysql2 gem which throws [this error](https://codeshare.io/X8ByPK).

Any help on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the full error message and the stack trace into your question instead of linking a photo? People might want to search for parts of the message for file names on the internet and therefore it is much harder to help you when people cannot copy-paste that information from the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3 -- --srcdir=/opt/homebrew/include/mysql/`